GitLab Runner Docker Executor and S3 cache
even with the multiple posts over the internet, I can't figure out how to make my GitLab-Runner working...
I'm using GitLab CE 17.0.0 + 2 GitLab Runners 17.0.0, one hosted on an AlmaLinux 8 server and one hosted on a Windows 11 computer.
Everything worked fine but I would like to set up the Shared Cache.
I've set up a MinIO server, hosted on an AlmaLinux 8. GitLab Container Registry is working well with my MinIO server.
Now I would like to set up my GitLab Runners. Both are using Docker executor. Config files are very similar:
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
connection_max_age = "15m0s"
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "runner-windows"
  url = "https://gitlab-url"
  id = 19
  token = "..."
  executor = "docker"

  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Shared = true

    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "minio-url:9000"
      AccessKey = "..."
      SecretKey = "..."
      BucketName = "gitlab-ci-cache"
      BucketLocation = "eu-east-1"

  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["gitlab-pipeline-cache:/cache"]
    shm_size = 0

This configuration is not using my MinIO server as cache server. A Docker volume "gitlab-pipeline-cache" is created and used.
From the runner hosts, if I use the MinIO client, I success to connect to my MinIO server, to upload files, etc. It's not a network issue.
Thank you!

EDIT 1: Add my .gitlab-ci.yml content + GitLab CI job output
.gitlab-ci.yml content
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG != null
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"

variables:
  CACHE_DIR: /cache/$CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE/$CI_PROJECT_NAME/$CI_PIPELINE_ID

stages:
  - .pre
  - touch

create_cache_dir:
  stage: .pre
  tags:
    - runner-almalinux8
  image: alpine:latest
  script:
    - mkdir --parents $CACHE_DIR/

create_file:
  stage: touch
  tags:
    - runner-windows
  image: alpine:latest
  script:
    - touch $CACHE_DIR/test_create_file.txt

Job output (.pre)
Running with gitlab-runner 17.0.0 (44feccdf)
  on runner-almalinux8 -_vLbzjNv, system ID: s_4f5c9ad29d6f
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:02
Using Docker executor with image alpine:latest ...
Pulling docker image alpine:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:05455a08881ea9cf0e752bc48e61bbd71a34c029bb13df01e40e3e70e0d007bd for alpine:latest with digest alpine@sha256:c5b1261d6d3e43071626931fc004f70149baeba2c8ec672bd4f27761f8e1ad6b ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner--vlbzjnv-project-116-concurrent-0 via runner-almalinux8...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/<group>/<project>/.git/
Checking out 456a298a as detached HEAD (ref is 1.0.0-rc1)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
Using docker image sha256:05455a08881ea9cf0e752bc48e61bbd71a34c029bb13df01e40e3e70e0d007bd for alpine:latest with digest alpine@sha256:c5b1261d6d3e43071626931fc004f70149baeba2c8ec672bd4f27761f8e1ad6b ...
$ mkdir --parents $CACHE_DIR/
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded

Job output (touch)
Running with gitlab-runner 17.0.0 (44feccdf)
  on runner-windows cc5wbtykV, system ID: s_4f5c9ad29d6f
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:08
Using Docker executor with image alpine:latest ...
Using helper image:  registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-v17.0.0
Pulling docker image registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-v17.0.0 ...
Using docker image sha256:cb32fd9b1984b484e20e7b6806bd3a0ef5304abee2f0c64d5b38e1234c2a7bf5 for registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-v17.0.0 with digest registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper@sha256:aa094d2434e42a61215a64dfb50fb9b9dc29d81e4d708c1c896d0818a5d6f873 ...
Pulling docker image alpine:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:1d34ffeaf190be23d3de5a8de0a436676b758f48f835c3a2d4768b798c15a7f1 for alpine:latest with digest alpine@sha256:77726ef6b57ddf65bb551896826ec38bc3e53f75cdde31354fbffb4f25238ebd ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-cc5wbtykv-project-326-concurrent-0 via runner-windows...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/<group>/<project>/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 456a298a as detached HEAD (ref is 1.0.0-rc1)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
Using docker image sha256:1d34ffeaf190be23d3de5a8de0a436676b758f48f835c3a2d4768b798c15a7f1 for alpine:latest with digest alpine@sha256:77726ef6b57ddf65bb551896826ec38bc3e53f75cdde31354fbffb4f25238ebd ...
$ touch $CACHE_DIR/test_create_file.txt
touch: /cache/<group>/<project>/3089/test_create_file.txt: No such file or directory
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1


It is now clear what kind of problem do you have. How does you ci job output look like? Some errors? How does your .gitlab-ci.yml look like? Did you double check you S3 access and secret keys and IAM policy?

Thank you for your reply. I've checked S3 credentials (same access key and secret key + IAM policy) with 'MinIO Client' (CLI tool) and it's working: I can push file into my S3 instance.
Also, I've edited my post to add GitLab-CI pipeline + jobs output.

The cache location is where GitLab will store cache bundles. To actually cache things you need to declare cacheable items:
default:
  cache:
    paths:
    - test_create_file.txt

job1:
  stage: build
  script:
  - echo "hello world" > test_create_file.txt

job2:
  stage: test
  script:
  - cat test_crete_file.txt


I'm trying to make it working, and I'll give answer later.

Because I'm using docker executor where each job are executed in separate Docker container, I have configured a docker volume to share files between containers. To use S3, I had to use caching like expected in GitLab and as Chris Becke said. Now, I've another error Uploading cache.zip to https://s3:9000/gitlab-ci-cache/project/116/3125-test-non_protected FATAL: received: 501 Not Implemented , but my runners try to use my s3 instance.

What S3 are you using? Ive used GitLab with Minio before - it looks like your S3 implementation doesn't support something GitLab needs.

I'm using GitLab-CE 17.0.0 and Minio S3 server AGPL edition version 2024-05-10T01:41:38Z
